# How to automatically diff changes from master database?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, database

I have a problem, which I can’t get around. I thought maybe someone of you already had some similar experience/problem and would be able to help the rest of the community or share some useful experience.

So the problem is following: I have a master database1, which I can’t modify directly but I need to add some additional data which is necessary to do the work in a reasonable manner, the only solution to that is to export it to .xlsx file, add the remaining tables with the needed information2 which is possible, but then there are some important things to consider:

-The data in the “master database” Is often rearranged, example: if someone was Ordinal number 1 the next time they update it can be number 5

-The data in the “master database” might change, example: some things can be added, some can be removed

-The data in the master database can be modified, example: values might change

So the question now becomes: How to export this to .xlsx, add my own tables and data, and then manage to “diff?” it everytime the master db is chaged, without losing the added data or the added data to mismatch it to other rows?

Did anyone manage to achieve this?

[image: Image with tables]

Comment: Not clear what you want to do. Is the "master database" a single list of data? What does "add the remaining tables with needed information" mean? Are you just adding extra columns to the "master database" list? What, precisely, are the changes that might occur between successive versions of the "master database"? And what do you want to do in response to these changes? What is significance of "ordinal number" (affects ordering of rows?). What does 'manage to "diff?" it' actually mean?

Comment: So pretty much what I mean by "master database" is : "A database which i can't control, I can't edit it, I can just read the data from it".  Yes It mean's adding extra columns to the "master database" in excel which i can't edit directly, just the exported .xlsx version. Changes can be following : items can be added, deleted, edited, rearranged ( for example 1 - water might become 1337 - water, the ordinal number and pretty much the whole information can change). I want to merge the newest changes to my exported version with added columns....

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is effectively that of two tables (or data lists in Excel terminology). One table is the latest version of your "master database", the other is the version you have previously processed (by adding columns, etc).

What follows is a fairly lengthy and generic description of the process involved in developing a suitable solution. Given the fairly general nature of the question this is unavoidable. Please ask questions in comments if anything is unclear.

The first task is to decide which column or column(s) you are going to use for the purposes of comparing the two tables. You want to identify what in database terminology is called the table's "key". This is the column (or combination of columns) whose values are unique to each row. For example, if your master database is primarily about items, then the `Item Serial Number` might be the key (unique to each row of the table). If, alternatively, the master database is primarily about people, then it might be that the combination of `Username` and `User Lastname` that provides the key.

Knowledge of how the master database is created and why it is created may be helpful in identifying the column(s) which provide the key. You might also want to ask the IT team or other group responsible for technical management of the "master database" about its key(s). Because of their importance in identifying rows, columns which act as keys are generally not allowed by database designers to have their values modified within the rows of a table.

Once the key column(s) are identified, comparison between the two tables is made on the basis of the the values held in these columns. Calling a new version of the "master database" *Table_New* and the previous .xlsx version *Table_Previous*, the process of comparing the two tables involves matching rows. Two rows ***match*** when the values in the key column(s) of the matched row in one table are identical to the values in the (same) key column(s) of the matched row in the other table.

The following three types of detailed comparisons are needed:

1. For each row in *Table_New* determine if there is a matching row in *Table_Previous*. Unmatched rows in *Table_New* represent newly added rows in the "master database".
2. Reversing the process, for each row in *Table_Previous* determine if there is a matching row in *Table_New*. Unmatched rows in *Table_Previous* are rows which have been deleted from the "master database".
3. For each row which is matched between *Table_New* and *Table_Previous*,  compare each common non-key column in *Table_New* with that in *Table_Previous*. If all pairs of values are identical between the two tables, then the row in *Table_New* has not been changed. Otherwise, it has been changed.

(Note that if, for some reason and contrary to the assumptions made, values in key columns do get changed this will manifest itself as a row being deleted from the "master database" and a new row being added. The added and deleted rows will be regarded as unrelated, rather than as a single row which has been changed. This happens because the changed row in *Table_New* will no longer match to its previous match in *Table_Previous*, so will be a classed as new row; similarly, the previously matched row in *Table_Previous* will no longer match to the corresponding (but changed) row  in *Table_New*, so will be classed as a deleted row.)

The 3 comparisons result in 4 possible outcomes for each row in the two tables

- A row in *Table_New* is not matched to any row in *Table_Previous*. This outcome is that a new row has been added to the "master database"
- A row in *Table_Previous* is not matched to any row in *Table_New*. This outcome is that a row has been deleted from the "master database".
- A row is matched between *Table_New* and *Table_Previous* but some values in the non-key columns are differ between the two tables: This outcome is that the row has been changed in the "master database".
- A row is matched between *Table_New* and *Table_Previous* all values in the non-key columns are the same in both tables. This outcome is that the row has been left unchanged in the "master database".

For each of these 4 outcomes, you will need to specify what action you want to take. Presumably, you will want to create a new version of *Table_Previous* to reflect the outcomes of the comparisons.

What these actions should be depends very much on the business requirement you are trying to satisfy. For example, if the "master database" is based on a list of active items (such stock lines held in a warehouse, current employees or work projects in progress) it is possible that your processing of that might want to retain the history after the items are no longer active (so keeping information about obsolescent stock lines, former employees and completed/abandoned projects).

Any guess at your business requirement would be speculative, so a line is drawn under this matter for the moment.

Instead, attention turns to the comparisons noted at 1, 2 and 3 above.

The first matter to note is that, in Excel, it is easier to identify whether a single value is in a list rather than whether two or more values are all contained separate lists.Therefore, one trick to consider if you have more than one key column is to use concatenation (or similar) to create a new artificial column which can act as a key on its own. Eg `"User Name"`&" "&`"User LastName"`.

Having a single key means the `MATCH` function can be used to test if a row in one table matches (in the sense defined above) to a row in the other table. The phrase to use is

`=MATCH(key_from_row_in_one_table, column_of_keys_in_other_table,0)`

and this returns the position of the row in the `other_table` if a match is found and `#N/A` otherwise. If necessary, the error can be trapped using functions such as `IFERROR` or phrases such as `=IF(ISNA(find_matched_row),one_thing,something_else)`.

To organise the comparisons, an approach with 3 worksheets might be suitable:

- Sheet1: An imported but unprocessed version of the latest "master database" (Table_New)
- Sheet2: The previous (.xlsx version) processed version of the master database complete with added columns, etc (Table_Previous)
- Sheet3: The updated version of *Table_Previous* derived from the comparisons of Sheet1 and Sheet2.

The comparisons can be performed by first, if necessary, adding a single key column to Sheet1 and Sheet2 formed by concatenating (or otherwise combining) the actual key columns. Also add to each table columns *Match* and *Changed*. The *Match* column in each worksheet will be based on the `MATCH` function previously outlined and will contain the position of the matching row in the other worksheet or `#N/A` if there is no match. For matched rows, the *Changed* column can be used to identify if the two matched rows share all the same non-key values. This might be as simple as a formula delivering `TRUE` or `FALSE` or something more extensive which identifies which columns have been changed. (What is actually done here should be determined by business requirements.)

Sheet3 should be derived either from Sheet1 (if the business requirement is largely centred on what is in the latest "master database") or both Sheet1 and Sheet2 (if the business requirement is centred on the "master database" and how it has changed over time).

In the former case, the added columns for rows showing as matched to a row in Sheet2 will be added to Sheet3 using the Sheet2 values. Or, if these added columns are calculated from columns which are present in the "master database", recalculated if the *Changed* column on Sheet1 indicates a change has been made. Extensive use of the `INDEX` function is likely if formulae are used to achieve this. If desired, the results in Sheet3 can contain a *Status* column to identify which rows of the results were added in the latest "master database" and which were changed. This column could be organised to hold the version number and/or date associated with this latest "master database".

In the latter case, Sheet3 will be mainly based on Sheet2 but with some rows from Sheet1 added. The new rows will be those identified as unmatched in Sheet1, and it is possible to use formulae in Sheet3 to add these rows. (The trick here is to find a way of "indexing" these unmatched rows in Sheet 1 and assign them with index numbers of 1, 2, 3,... and then in Sheet3 to match to these index numbers (`MATCH` function, again) and use the `INDEX/MATCH` construct to "pull" these unmatched rows  into Sheet3. These new rows will most easily be added at the end of the data list in Sheet3 (but re-ordering can be undertaken once they have been added). The additional column values for these new rows will need to be added/calculated. The *Status* column can now also be used to identify rows deleted from the "master database".

Once satisfied that Sheet3 contains the correct values, and as part of effective version management, it might be sensible to "fix" the values on it through copy/paste special. In addition, if there is a desired ordering to the rows this can also be undertaken prior to finalisation.

When a subsequent version of the "master database" is processed, Sheet2 is updated by replacing its contents with what is on Sheet3. Sheet1 is updated with the new version of the "master database" and Sheet3 is updated with the results of comparisons between the updated Sheet1 and the updated Sheet2.

Comment: Firstly I would like to thank you for your massive contribution. I'am very sad that I have to dissapoint you but I just can't make use of the knowledge you provided because I'am too tech illiterate to make it work. I don't understand the "database key" mechanic and I think there isn't anything that is unique in every record. The IT support sadly won't be able to assist me with this issue. I thought maybe someone is aware of a built-in feature of excel that can automate the process you explained.   1/2

Comment: I would like to apologize to you for the time you spent on explaing all the mechanics that could solve my issue but i just won't be able to make it work. But not all hope is lost! Maybe someone had some similar issue and after seeing your answer will be able to solve it! Thank you again for providing a great solution and explanation! 2/2

Comment: You do have a reasonably tricky problem and whilst Excel has some really broad capabilities there isn't any "built-in feature" (as far as I am aware) that directly solves your problem. This is not meant to be disparaging or insulting but I suggest you find something equivalent to "The Idiot's Guide to Databases". Something like this may help you to understand the concept of a "key", why it is so useful generally and for your problem specifically. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you again for the input. Cheers mate.

Comment: Okay, actually there is a different unique number in each row! But it can be in two different columns ,depening on the scenarion. Could I somehow Glue those added columns to the corresponding unique ID after i somehow merge the changes?

Comment: If you modify your original question (or perhaps just add to it) to reflect what how this "unique number" manifests itself, then it may be possible to modify the answer to get you to a workable solution.